# need help, positioning values in rrdtool

Tags: rrdtool

```
DEF:clients=cccam.rrd:kliensek:AVERAGE  
DEF:activeclients=cccam_actclient.rrd:activeclients:AVERAGE  
"LINE1:clients#0000FF:Connected   clients" COMMENT:" \n"  
"LINE2:activeclients#99FF00:Active clients" COMMENT:" \n"  
GPRINT:clients:LAST:'Current'\%5.0lf%s COMMENT:" \n"  
GPRINT:clients:MIN:'Min: '\%5.0lf%s  COMMENT:" \n" 
GPRINT:clients:MAX:"Max:\:%5.0lf%s\n"  
GPRINT:activeclients:LAST:'Current'\%5.0lf%s COMMENT:" \n"  
GPRINT:activeclients:MIN:'Min: '\%5.0lf%s COMMENT:" \n"   
GPRINT:activeclients:MAX:"Max:\:%5.0lf%s\n"
```

How I can place values, in this form, like this:

http://d.pr/Okcr+

Number under numbers, caption under captions..

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure you set the relevant spaces correctly in order to make everything line up correctly.  For example:

```
COMMENT:'     Clients  Connected\n'
COMMENT:'LAST '
GPRINT:clients:LAST:'%8.0lf%s ' 
GPRINT:activeclients:LAST:'%8.0lf%s\n'
COMMENT:'MIN  '
GPRINT:clients:MIN:'%8.0lf%s ' 
GPRINT:activeclients:MIN:'%8.0lf%s\n'
COMMENT:'MAX  '
GPRINT:clients:MAX:'%8.0lf%s ' 
GPRINT:activeclients:MAX:'%8.0lf%s\n'
```